# Check my Latitude and Longitude within my circle of area in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I'm working with geolocation in ionic 3 to get the current position of latitude and longitude. It's wokring fine but now I need to check if that latitude and longitude are present in a certain range of an area.

**Example:** I have one app that only works inside my room and I'm trying to check whether my location is given surrounding area or not.

How can I archieve this with Ionic 3?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use Geofence but it seems abandened so I end up with using [google.maps.Circle()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)

i.e. (`mkr` is your marker)

```
let serviceRange = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: this.map,
    center:  {'lat':mkr.latitude, 'lng':mkr.longitude},
    radius: Math.sqrt(mkr.distance) * 1000,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw a square in the map centered around your room gps position.
Then you get the max and min latitude respectively from the top corners and bottom corners. And max and min longitude respectively from right and left corners.

Then when you get a gps position, you make sure that its lat and lng are within those previously defined min max latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

[Ionic Geofence](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geofence/)

- Using geofence you can easily achieve your requirements.